# is razor html helper put extra load during html conversion?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I found `mvc html helper` quite useful and easy to use. thats amazing invent.

but im wondering, whether it put extra load during html conversion because im working on where **performance is must**.  if it is so, then what i will normally prefer ? if my work can be accomplish easily with simple `html` control then what is recommended `html helper` or `simple html` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the Razor Helpers, in order to optimize your response performance you should use caching like [ASP.NET In-Memory Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx) or [App-Fabric Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731%28v=azure.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Html Helpers have virtually now impact on performance when compared to normal Html.
They also allow you to reuse code efficiently. Also, being a method you can pass parameters to it. Use normal html only if you're not planning to reuse that html code.

Plus Html.Helpers being C# (or VB.NET) code will be compiled, hence they'll run very fast. You needn't worry about performance from this point of view